# Q : Python CSV - Key Error when plotting

Tags: python, csv, plot

What I'm trying to plot a a dataframe but I'm encountering some errors that I don't know how to solve.

Python Code:

```
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import date,time,datetime
    import pandas as pd
    import csv

    df = pd.read_csv('MainD2.csv', parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)


    df["Time_Stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time_Stamp"]) # convert to Datetime

    df_filter = df[df["Curr"].le(3.0)] # new df with less or equal to 0.5
    #print(df_filter)

    where = (df_filter[df_filter["Time_Stamp"].diff().dt.total_seconds() > 1] ["Time_Stamp"] - pd.Timedelta("1s")).astype(str).tolist() # Find where diff > 1 second
    df_filter2 = df[df["Time_Stamp"].isin(where)] # Create new df with those
    #print(df_filter2)
    df_filter2["AC_Input_Current"] = 0.0 # Set c1 to 0.0

    #df_filter2

    df = df.set_index("Time_Stamp")
    df_filter2 = df_filter2.set_index("Time_Stamp")
    df.loc[df_filter2.index] = df_filter2

    def getMask(start,end):
        mask = (df['Time_Stamp'] > start) & (df['Time_Stamp'] <= end)
        return mask;

    start = '2017-06-26 01:05:00'
    end = '2017-06-26 01:20:00'

    timerange = df.loc[getMask(start, end)]

    timerange.plot(x='Time_Stamp', y='AC_Input_Current', style='-', color='black')*
```

*------------------ *Plotting Part -------------------*

`timerange.plot(x='Time_Stamp', y='AC_Input_Current', style='-', color='black')`

I have encountered this error when trying to plot :

```
KeyError: 'Time_Stamp'
```

Comment: I think that it can't find the column 'Time_Stamp', probably because you made it as index. Either run reset_index() befpre plotting or when referencing the column in the index use .index...

Comment: @lorenzori I still encounter the `Key Error` after adding `df.reset_index(drop=true)` before the `def getMask` function... any idea how I should resolve this ?

Comment: before you run the .plot, could you print the columns (timerange.columns.values) please?

Comment: I tried to print `timerange` but it had the `Key Error: 'Time_Stamp'` , I guess the error is on the `def:` function..

Comment: btw, in getMask you have a semicolon after the "return".

Comment: Oh my, Thanks for letting me know! Just a small habit from doing C++ . 
Btw, I'm still unable to get a time range within the `df` to plot.. :( Is there any way you can help me what I can do?

Comment: usually the standard way of making time indexes in Pandas is to use the DatetimeIndex: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html